# Advance slick slider when image in gallery is clicked (multiple slick sliders on one page)

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I came across this modification for slick slider for advancing when clicking on the current image (see below). When I implement it on my page with multiple galleries it advances all galleries when I click on one, not only the one selected. Is there a possibility to use e.g. "this" selector in here? 
http://codepen.io/ethanclevenger91/pen/MYNGrN

```
window.onload=function(){
    $slideshow = $('.slider').slick({
        dots:false,
        autoplay:false,
        arrows:false,
        adaptiveHeight: true,
        slidesToShow:1,
        slidesToScroll:1
    });
    $(".slide").click(function() {
        $slideshow.slick('slickGoTo', parseInt($slideshow.slick('slickCurrentSlide'))+1);
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you using a single command to define all the galleries? If so, this might be the reason for all of them to advance, as `$slideshow` holds a reference to multiple galleries

Comment: thank you for the reply, that seems to be the problem indeed!
do i then have to write the script for each element with an id?
e.g.   $slideshow = $('#slider1').slick({
  $slideshow = $('#slider2').slick({
etc.  ?

Comment: You might be able to do it dynamically. Please add more galleries to your codepen, so I could better understand the structure, this way I will be able to help more

Comment: i created a codepen with my html / css, you can see it here: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bedQVg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOGmWo?editors=1010

The main idea is to define each slider separately.

First, define an object to hold all the sliders:

```
var sliders = {};
```

Then, looping through all the sliders, extracting the ID and saving a reference to the newly defined slider in our map, indexed by the ID:

```
$('.slider').each(function (index, slider) {
    var id = slider.getAttribute('id');
    console.log(id);
    sliders[id] = $(slider).slick({ ... })
});
```

Now, on the click handler, we determine to which slider do the clicked slide belong to, using `$(this).closest('.slider')` and using progressing it.

```
$('.slide').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.slider').get(0).getAttribute('id');
    var $slideshow = sliders[id];
    $slideshow.slick('slickGoTo', parseInt($slideshow.slick('slickCurrentSlide'))+1);
});
```